# what are the benefits of using smaller temporary views vs larger persistent views on memory mapped files

Tags: memory-mapped-files

i am fiddling to make my own storage engine, it is mostly for my own education.

so far i have a very good working solution with memory mapped files, but something is bothering me and i dont want to get bit by this later. i am basically mapping a view of my whole file and only create a new view if i have to resize the file. i know that this approach has one obvious drawback: maximum size, for now but i can live with that, i really dont intend to store data exceeding gigabytes.

but are there other considerations? how does this one large mapping interact with the os memory management routines, what about the long run? are there performance and fragmentation issues that i could run into by using this approach?

using smaller views over areas of the file i need will certainly remove the limit of the size of the database i can make, but then that is an extra layer of management i have to do in my storage engine, that i would rather avoid if i could.

i have only just scratched the top of an iceberg, and if someone could be my radar i could surely avoid some fatal crash!